# nested Grouping in Linq

Tags: linq, nested, grouping

This is the data table I have in my code:

```
PackID   PackName       FilterID      SystemID    SystemName
 18       ThirdRep       0             5           ABC
 18       ThirdRep       1             5           ABC
 18       ThirdRep       3             3           XYZ
 17       SecondRep      0             5           ABC
```

I need to Group all the system under the Package and group all the filters under the system in Linq. I want to transform this data as below.

Collection of Package (an example of the expected result):

```
PackageID  :17
PackName   :SecondRep     
SystemCollection [ SystemID:5 , SystemName : ABC, FilterCollection [FilterID:1,FilterID:0 ] ]


PackageID  :18
PackName   :ThirdRep      
SystemCollection [ SystemID:5 , SystemName : ABC, FilterCollection [FilterID:0 ] ]
```

My code:

```
var groupedData = from b in dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  group b by new
                  {
                      PackageID = b.Field<Int32>("PackageID"),
                      PackageName = b.Field<string>("PackageName"),
                  } into g
                  select new ReportPackage
                  {
                      PackageId = g.Key.PackageID,
                      PackageName = g.Key.PackageName,
                      SystemCollection = g.Select(c => new ReportSystem
                      {
                          SystemId = c.Field<int>("SystemID"),
                          SystemName = c.Field<string>("SystemName"),
                          FilterCollection = g.Select(b => new ReportFilter
                          {
                              FilterId = b.Field<int>("FilterID"),
                          }).ToList()
                      }).GroupBy(x => x.SystemId).Select(v => v.First()).ToList()
                  };
```

The above code is not helping me much. All the filters are getting added to the collection irrespective of System id.

Comment: PackageID 18 has two different SystemID 5 and 3. Why did you select only the SystemID 5?

Comment: @Dzienny.. i didnt get your Question. My Code may be wrong . I was trying to Group systemId under the package id and  filters to be grouped under the SystemId

Comment: I was referring to the expected results example, not to the code.

Comment: @Dzienny ho!.Sorry for that.. PackageID 18 needs to have both systemID 5 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You should first group the filters by the `SystemID` and `SystemName` and then perform select, instead of the other way around.

Try:

```
var groupedData = from b in dataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  group b by new
                  {
                      PackageID = b.Field<int>("PackageID"),
                      PackageName = b.Field<string>("PackageName"),
                  } into g
                  select new ReportPackage
                  {
                      PackageId = g.Key.PackageID,
                      PackageName = g.Key.PackageName,
                      SystemCollection = (from e in g
                                          group e by new
                                          {
                                              SystemID = b.Field<int>("SystemID"),
                                              SystemName = b.Field<string>("SystemName")
                                          } into fg
                                          select new ReportSystem
                                          {
                                              fg.SystemID,
                                              fg.SystemName,
                                              FilterCollection = fg.Select(f => new ReportFilter
                                              {
                                                  FilterID = f.Field<int>("FilterID")
                                              }                                                 
                                          }).ToList()
                  }
```